# Generar productos variables con Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

es la primera vez que realizo esto y no se muy bien como realizarlo. Lo que quiero hacer es como hace Wordpress cuando creas un producto variable.

1. Añades los atributos que quieres
2. con los atributos seleccionados se te abren multi-select y eliges los valores que deseas.
3. Luego guardar los atributos
4. Ya te aparecen en la pestaña de variaciones
5. Le das a generar y te sale un desplegable, uno por cada variación para rellenar precio, etc..

Hasta ahora he creado una tabla atributos y otra relacionada que se llama terminos, y los terminos van dentro de su atributo.
También he hecho un select donde me carga los atributos, selecciono el que quiero y me sale el multi-select para elegir los terminos que yo quiero para las variaciones.

Bien lo que no se como utilizar esto, para que me genere las variaciones posibles y poder rellenarlas y después ya insertarlas.

```
Table Atributos:
+-------------------------------+
| id | name    | slug   |  tipo |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | Género  | genero |   0   |
| 2  | Tallas  | tallas |   0   |
+----+---------+----------------+

Table Terminos:
+----------------------------------------------+
| id | atributo_id | termino   |     slug      |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+
| 1  |      2      | Masculino |   masculino   |
| 2  |      2      | Femenino  |   femenino    |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Tengo un select donde cargo las opciones de base de datos de los Atributos.

```
<select class="form-control myinputs col-4 inlinBlock" name="selAtributo[]" id="selAtributo">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona atriburo</option>
       @foreach ($atributos as $item)
         <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
<a class="btn btnGuardar corrigeBtnAnadir" onclick="myFunction()" style="color: #fff;">Añadir</a>
```

Al darle al botón añadir traigo los terminos que tiene este atributo y un select multiple para poder añadir todos los terminos que quiero.

```
function myFunction() {
        var atributo = document.getElementById("selAtributo").value;
        $.get("add-producto/select_atributo/" + atributo, function (data) {
        data.elAtributo = data.elAtributo || {};
        var atributoName = data.elAtributo.slug;
        var atributoNameBueno = data.elAtributo.name;
        var htmlDivContainer = `<div class="form-group select-container-${atributoName}"></div>`;
        var htmlSelectContainer = `<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo" name="${atributoName}[]" multiple="multiple" id="${atributoName}"></select>`;
        $("#terminos1").append(`${atributoNameBueno}`);
        $("#terminos1").append(htmlDivContainer);
        $(`#terminos1 div.select-container-${atributoName}`).html(
        htmlSelectContainer
        );
        var htmlOptions = (data.terminos || []).reduce(
        (html, termino, index) =>
        html + `<option value="${termino.id}">${termino.termino}</option>`,
        ""
        );
        $(`#terminos1 select[name="${atributoName}[]"`).html(htmlOptions).select2();
        console.log(data);
        });
        
    }
```

Esto me funciona perfecto, puedo añadir tantos multi-select por los atributos que quiera y poner los terminos que quiera.
Pero aquí añado un botón para guardar los atributos añadidos para luego utilizarlo en otra pestaña, pero no se como actuar aquí ya.

Quiero que sin guardarlos en la Base de datos pueda generar las variaciones totales y entonces rellenarlas, no se si me explico bien. Está claro que me falta también las tablas para guardar los productos y sus variaciones, pero queria solucionar esto primero.

La tabla productos y variaciones pensaba hacerla así:

PRODUCTOS

```
+----------------------------+-------------+
| id | name                  | descipcion  |
+----+-----------------------+-------------+
| 1  | Camiseta manga corta  | descripción |
| 2  | Kimono                | descripción |
+----+-----------------------+-------------+
```

VARIABLES PRODUCTOS

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id | product_id | variant  | value     |   precio  |  precio oferta  |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1          | genero   | masculino |     10    |       null      |
| 2  | 1          | talla    |    S      |     30    |        19       |
| 3  | 1          | talla    |    L      |           |                 |
| 4  | 1          | talla    |   XXL     |           |                 |   
+----+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Es decir que tienes dos tabs y quieres hacer viajar data entre ellos? O quieres hacer viajar datos entre vistas distintas?

Comment: Hola @L.Flor si hay que hacer viajar la info de la una a la otra, para poder generar las variaciones

Comment: Pero no has respondido, si es entre tabs o entre vistas, si es entre vistas, fácilmente puedes enviar la data mediante un Request, si es entre tabs, puedes comunicar la data con Javascript

Comment: Perdona me confundi al contestarte, es entre tabs @L.Flor